# Как получить номер фискального регистратора ШТРИХ-М-02Ф?

Tags: java

Мне нужно программно получить полный номер фискального регистратора(ФР), я использую метод `getPhysicalDeviceName`:

```java
private static ShtrihFiscalPrinter printer;
String result = printer.getPhysicalDeviceName();
```

В этом случае я получаю только последние 5 цифр: `ШТРИХ-М-02Ф, № 50248` 
Есть программа `Тест драйвера ККТ`, он выдают то, что нужно: `ШТРИХ-М-02Ф № 0097830008050248`

Как мне получить этот номер?

Comment: Ссылку дайте на API, который вы используете

Comment: @Barmaley, [Вот документ](https://www.shtrih-m.ru/docs/download.php?file=32972&iblock=21), я использую его, сам код драйвера вот [тут](https://github.com/shtrih-m/javapos_shtrih)

Comment: @Barmaley jpos113 - использую эту версию

Comment: я нашел.. `printer.readTable(18,1,1);`